# How to determine whether the number is float or integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to write this query in SQL Server:

```
IF isFloat(@value) = 1
BEGIN
    PRINT 'this is float number'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'this is integer number'
END
```

Please help me out with this, thanks.

Comment: Would you count the value "1.0" as an integer or a float?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
declare @value float = 1

IF FLOOR(@value) <> CEILING(@value)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'this is float number'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'this is integer number'
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Martin, under certain circumstances your solution gives an incorrect result if you encounter a value of 1234.0, for example. Your code determines that 1234.0 is an integer, which is incorrect.

This is a more accurate snippet:

```
if cast(cast(123456.0 as integer) as varchar(255)) <> cast(123456.0 as varchar(255)) 
begin 
  print 'non integer' 
end 
else 
begin 
  print 'integer' 
end
```

Regards,

Nico

Comment: To me `123456.0` is the same as `123456` and is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @value FLOAT = 1.50
IF CONVERT(int, @value) - @value <> 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'this is float number'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'this is integer number'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

> See whether the below code will help. In the below values only 9,
>   2147483647, 1234567 are eligible as Integer. We can create this as
>   function and can use this.

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE(MY_FIELD VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
VALUES('9.123'),('1234567'),('9'),('2147483647'),('2147483647.01'),('2147483648'), ('2147483648ABCD'),('214,7483,648')

SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE CHARINDEX('.',MY_FIELD) = 0 AND CHARINDEX(',',MY_FIELD) = 0       
AND ISNUMERIC(MY_FIELD) = 1 AND CONVERT(FLOAT,MY_FIELD) / 2147483647 <= 1
DROP TABLE MY_TABLE
```

> OR

```
DECLARE @num VARCHAR(100)
SET @num = '2147483648AS'
IF ISNUMERIC(@num) = 1 AND @num NOT LIKE '%.%' AND @num NOT LIKE '%,%' 
BEGIN
    IF CONVERT(FLOAT,@num) / 2147483647 <= 1
        PRINT 'INTEGER'
    ELSE
        PRINT 'NOT-INTEGER' 
END
ELSE
    PRINT 'NOT-INTEGER'
```