# Only allow whole numbers as variables in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, decimal

What is a simple script to identify if a variable is a decimal and not allow it? I only want whole numbers as variables received from the program running on top of SQL Server 2008 so if I get a decimal or negative number or number with text/symbols, I want to throw up an error.

Comment: We need more details on what you are trying to do and what you have tried. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Are you trying to reject inserts and updates on a particular field? Are you trying to filter searches?

Comment: When a user enters a quantity on the UI and if it is a decimal, negative or number with text, I want to reject the entry by showing an error message. I have tried:
  IF @Scan < 1
   BEGIN
    SELECT 'Decimals not allowed.'
   END

Comment: Edit your question to include that information.

Comment: @StillLearnin, his question is clear, he wants to validate the parameter value.

Comment: Possibly useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752722/how-to-determine-whether-the-number-is-float-or-integer-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be something simpler, but try this.

```
declare @val varchar(10) = '1.0'

if isnumeric(@val) = 1
    and charindex('.', @val) = 0
    and charindex('-', @val) = 0
    and charindex('$', @val) = 0

    select 'Valid'
else
    select 'Not valid'
```

Or use combination of above with regex.  I'm no regex expert, but i'm sure this can be done with just patindex.

```
declare @val varchar(10) = '1.0'

if isnumeric(@val) = 1
    and patindex('%[$.-]%', @val) = 0

    select 'Valid'
else
    select 'Not Valid'
```